# Error using bsCheckboxDirective (AngularStrap)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I'm receiving this error trying to use the bsCheckboxDirective of AngularStrap:

```
error/$injector/unpr?p0=$$animateReflowProvider%20<-%20$$animateReflow%20<-%20bsCheckboxDirective
```

I suppose I'm missing some requirement but...
Well, I ran out of ideas right now. Does anyone saw it before? Any tips?
I haven't seen this $$animateReflow defined anywhere though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you included all scripts listed in the [quick start guide](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/README.md).  Specifically, angular-animate must be included to supply the animateReflow service.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//rawgithub.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/master/dist/angular-strap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="//rawgithub.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/master/dist/angular-strap.tpl.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I thought everything was ok but there was a mismatch between my angularjs version (straight from the cdn) and my local ngAnimate file. At least I learnt something about keeping things up-to-date. You pointed me in the right direction. Thank you.